# Склонение топонима

Tags: орфография

В предложном падеже: *Килии* или *Килие* от слова *КилиЯ*?

Answer (score 1):

О Килии. Название восходит к "Ахиллия", поэтому логично склонять как обыное слово особого склонения, по образцу "Мария" или "Россия".

А вообще вопрос интересный. Полагаю, есть масса топонимов, которые трудно классифицировать подобным образом. И тогда возможны варианты.

Answer (score 0):

**Килии**. Существительные женского рода на -ия в предложном падеже единственного числа имеют окончание -И (заканчиваются на -ии).

Comment: Здесь-то да, а вообще как узнать-то наверняка, что оно - женского рода. 
Хотя и в этом случае возможны варианты. Мадам Думбия (жена футболиста Думбии) точно ли по этому типу склоняется? Я не уверен.